# three.js fontloader cannot read generateshapes of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the following code that generates some meshes. I want to add 3d text to the scene but when i do this i get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'generateShapes' of undefined

this is the code i have to generate the meshes and the 3d text:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var finalSize = 450;
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
```

the var font is undefined why?

```
var font = fontLoader.load( 'css/arial_bold.json');
var fontColor = textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000, overdraw: 0.5 });

for (var i = javascriptProjects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    var object = {};
    object.scale = javascriptProjects[i].baseImageData["0"] / finalSize;
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(javascriptProjects[i].baseImageData["0"]/object.scale,javascriptProjects[i].baseImageData["1"]/object.scale, 10, 10);
    object.texture = textureLoader.load( "data/"+ javascriptProjects[i].base_image );
    object.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: object.texture, overdraw: 0.5, transparent: true } );
    object.material.opacity = 0.5;
    object.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, object.material);
```

//the line below generates the error

```
    object.FontGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( javascriptProjects[i].project_name , {
        font: font,
        size: 50,
        height: 2,
        curveSegments: 12,
        bevelThickness: 1,
        bevelSize: 1,
        bevelEnabled: false
    });
    object.textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( object.FontGeo, fontColor );
    object.textMesh.position.x = object.location.x;
    object.textMesh.position.y = object.location.y;
    object.textMesh.position.z = object.location.z - 100;

    scene.add(object.textMesh);

    object.location = new THREE.Vector3(x, 120, y);
    object.id = "" + javascriptProjects[i].project_id;
    object.mesh.position.x = object.location.x;
    object.mesh.position.y = object.location.y;
    object.mesh.position.z = object.location.z;


    scene.add(object.mesh);
    meshes.push(object.mesh);
    objects.push(object);


    x += 600;
    if(i % 3 == 0){
        y += 600;
        x = 0;
    };
};
```

apparently font is undefined. why i don't see what i am doing wrong. Any suggestions would be great. If something is not clear let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can go through the debugger and see which of your variables are undefined.

Comment: see the updated answer for the undefined variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FontLoader.load()` is an asynchronous function call. This is why there is an `onLoad` call back function.

The library is calling `font.generateShapes()` before the `font` is loaded.

Use a pattern like this one, instead:

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( 'myFontFile.json', function ( font ) {

    // insert your code here

} );
```

See, for example, [this three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shadowmap_performance.html), and the three.js [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=font#api/loaders/FontLoader) .

three.js r.84